# When did Batman become considered the most intelligent being?

Tags: dc, batman, dceased

In DC, who/what is the most intelligent being has been discussed a lot in comics, series, etc. But I remember Lex Luthor being the top one always. However, in *DCeased*, this status has changed; even Lex refers to Batman as most intelligent.

[image: Luthor admits Batman is smarter]

Did this status change occur recently overall in DC comics or is it new in *DCeased*?

Comment: Strongly strongly related, perhaps even dupe, [Thaddeus' answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/162784/98028) to [Who are the two smartest people in the world? (DC Comics)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/14652/98028)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### DCeased is an Elseworld story out of the main DC continuity

**Tom Taylor**, one of the writers of *DCeased*, replies [here](https://twitter.com/TomTaylorMade/status/1100590650297208832) to a tweet stating that:

[image]

thereby confirming that it is indeed a sort of OoC Elseworlds story.

And for the fact the Luthor is downright smarter than Batman in every continuity, this is most likely a change made only for the DCeased continuity where, Batman *could* be the smartest person on Earth.

Someone like Luthor would never give up an opportunity to show his superiority; him acknowledging Batman's superiority supports the fact that *Batman is actually smarter than Lex*.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter whether DCeased is set in continuity. Everyone is still in character. DCeased is just a "What if Earth-0 got plagued by Zombies and the Heroes lost instead" scenario. Everyone is still in character, and every character is still in their current iteration, which means that Batman is smarter than Lex. Superman has also stated it before. Both Superman and Lex have stated that Bruce is the Smartest Man on Earth. And about the tweet reply by Tom Taylor to another tweet, that reply by Tom was not Batman or Lex related. The question asked by that random fan was whether the story is set in continuity, to which Tom replied "Out of continuity", and then Tom continued "So we can do more damage, or toy with your emotions". Tom is referring to the fact that he can kill any character he wants, that he can kill any character loved by the fans. He is NOT saying that anyone is out of character, which means that Bruce IS smarter than Lex, because everyone is still in character, because DCeased is literally a "What if" scenario for the current continuity of Earth-0, which means that the DCeased continuity only diverged from Earth-0 continuity because the Heroes had lost instead of overcoming the zombie apocalypse.

Even Superman knows that Bruce is smarter than Lex: Earth-0 continuity (Current DC Earth is Earth-0) https://comicvine1.cbsistatic.com/uploads/original/11127/111277832/5179226-oh%20god...2.png

"With Bruce out of commission, Lex Luthor may be the smartest man on this planet"

"With Bruce out of commission". There you go.

Look what we have here? Another panel, this time from the DC Universe/He-Man crossover. This is also Earth-0 continuity.
Look below :

Bruce is mentioned as the Smartest man in the realm.

https://www.google.com/search?q=smartest+man+in+the+realm+batman&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiWgvT9qIvuAhW8y3MBHcKvBr4Q2-cCegQIABAB&oq=smartest+&gs_lcp=ChJtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1pbWcQARgAMgQIIxAnMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADoHCCMQ6gIQJzoICAAQsQMQgwE6BwgAELEDEEM6BAgAEEM6BQgAELEDUJ4nWIpBYK1LaANwAHgAgAGsA4gBmBqSAQUzLTcuMpgBAKABAbABBcABAQ&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-img&ei=fcf3X9bPJ7yXz7sPwt-a8As&bih=600&biw=360&client=ms-opera-mobile&prmd=isnv#imgrc=9Jo5puAWgIOsqM

"Smartest man in the realm". Realm being Earth.

Altogether you have three incidences where Bruce is mentioned as the Smartest.

1.) First incident - The first scan of the first panel I sent.
Superman states it on Earth-0.

2.) Second incident - He-man crossover - Other heroes from the He-man universe state it when they enter Earth-0.

3.) Third Incident - Lex himself states it in DCeased - DCeased being a "What if Earth's Greatest Super-Heroes lost and got killed in a Zombie Pandemic" scenario of Earth-0.

So as you can see, Bruce is smarter than Lex.

As for when this happened? It happened in Earth-0 Continuity (The Current Mainstream Continuity)

Now about the Post-Crisis Continuity, the Post-Crisis Continuity has acknowledged that Post-Crisis Bruce and Post-Crisis Lex are equals. That's Post-Crisis continuity for the Post-Crisis Earth, NOT Earth-0.

Earth-0 Bruce Wayne > Earth-0 Lex Luthor

Post-Crisis Earth Bruce Wayne = Post-Crisis Earth Lex Luthor

Bruce and Lex being Equals on Post-Crisis Earth was mentioned in the Batman Confidential Trade Paperback synopsis titled "Rules of Engagement".

This was the synopsis written on the Trade Paperback of "Rules of Engagement". You can google it if you want.

"Like two sides of the same coin, Bruce Wayne and Lex Luthor are both brilliant billionaires with dark secrets. One is a criminal mastermind, the other dedicates his life to battling crime as the Dark Knight, Batman. But when both men go after the same government defense contract, they also find themselves sharing an assailant, a killer robot, designed by Wayne Enterprises. How did one of Batman's own creations turn against him? To solve this mystery, the world's greatest detective must dive into a world of industrial espionage, murder and political manipulation as he uncovers an attempt to take over the United States. Will Batman survive when matched against a mind as brilliant and cunning as his own?"

Oh and look what we have here? Another booklet detailing the History of the Post-Crisis Earth Batman, where Post-Crisis Earth Bruce and Post-Crisis Earth Lex are mentioned as Intellectual Equals.

"with an intellect rivalled only by the likes of Lex Luthor"

https://www.google.com/search?q=batman+with+a+mind+rivaled+only+by+lex+luthor&client=ms-opera-mobile&hl=en&prmd=ivsn&sxsrf=ALeKk00GyAKdCrBVp43yE-LBZe4t2Bts_Q:1610081542719&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiC2aaTxYvuAhU9yDgGHThBDXQQ_AUoAXoECA0QAQ&biw=360&bih=600#imgrc=JrOdO8p0rLrcRM

So yes, in terms of who is smarter :

Earth-0 Bruce Wayne > Earth-0 Lex Luthor

Post-Crisis Earth Bruce Wayne = Post-Crisis Earth Lex Luthor

Bruce Wayne has always been a highly Intelligent human being. On Post-Crisis Earth, Bruce is Lex's intellectual equal. While on Earth-0, Bruce is Lex's intellectual superior.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer in its own right, but rather an extended common on the answer above.

Comment: How is it not an answer? I read the book, and the guy above me contradicted what i said.

Comment: You seem to be more intent on "setting people straight" than actually answering the question (e.g. When did Batman become considered the most intelligent being?). Your answer doesn't address that, other than to contradict Shreedar's answer and by offering no evidence of your own.

Comment: So now i'm being judged by my username? I don't recall someone's username being relevant to an answer. And about evidence, when superman had lost his powers, superman had remarked that "with Bruce of out commission, Lex may be the smartest man on Earth" i'll give you the issue number.

Comment: Yes, actually providing evidence would be a fine way to improve this into an answer, rather than just a set of assertions, and would be worthy of upvote. Might I suggest that you also de-clutter the answer by removing references to what others have written. Your answer should stand alone.

Comment: https://comicvine1.cbsistatic.com/uploads/original/11127/111277832/5179226-oh%20god...2.png

Comment: Don't tell me. Add it to your answer and explain how it's relevant.

Comment: That's the link address to the image of the precise comicbook in which that comment had been made. That precise panel.

Comment: And when was that image published?  When did happen in the timeline.

Comment: That image happens on Earth-0. Everything that is Post-Flashpoint is Earth-0 continuity.

Comment: This answer needs tidying up. A simple explanation that directly answers the question, comic panel, and citation (issue, date) are all that is necessary. Not a confrontational train of thought.